# mod_rewrite to remove folder + extension works except for one folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Am having an extremely curious situation with my mod_rewrite. I have the following .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^approval/(.*)/(.*)/[0-9]$ /view/approval/$1/$2\.php [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^approval/(.*)/(.*)$ /view/approval/$1\.php?id=$2 [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^approval/(.*)$ /view/approval/$1\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)/(.*)/[0-9]$ /view/dashboard/$1/$2\.php [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)/(.*)$ /view/dashboard/$1\.php?id=$2 [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)$ /view/dashboard/$1\.php [NC]
```

The rewrite rules for approval work - they remove the "view" folder, and the .php (so `/view/approval/file/thisfile.php` becomes `/approval/file/thisfile`).

However, the same exact code and structure for dashboard not only does not work, it has a tendency to add .php. So `/view/dashboard/file/managethis.php` becomes `/view/dashboard/file/managethis\/.php/` (am escaping the slash)

All URLs are in a separate folder called "view", and all have the .php removed. How can I do this in one RewriteRule, rather than having to rewrite every folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.*` use `[^/]+` in your regex also no need to escape dot on right hand side:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  - [L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[0-9]/?$ /view/dashboard/$1/$2.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /view/dashboard/$1.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/?$ /view/dashboard/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Close, but the URL result was: /view/dashboard/files/manage/.php/

Comment: If URL in browser is `/dashboard/files/manage/` it will be silently rewritten to `/view/dashboard/files.php?id=manage` as regex is capturing only `[^/]+` which is without `/`

Comment: tried it the URL to see if it was rewriting, and it wasn't at all. Got a 404. But why would it work for approval, and not for dashboard? Even if I remove all other rewrites, dashboard still refuses to cooperate.

Comment: See updated answer but I suspect you have some other rules or some other .htaccess in your system.

Comment: Tried, still won't rewrite correctly. I have .htaccess in other folders, but all they do is add/deny from all.

Comment: I have a really stupid question - am testing my RewriteUrls, why is it that to remove /view/, it successfully matches on the left side (so ^view/(.*)$ then /$1), but will not actually rewrite?

Comment: Am accepting the answer as correct. I reset the .htaccess/apache a few times, and whatever quirks were there before stopped occurring.